# What libraries are needed for an efficient PHP-debugging on Windows SDK?

Tags: php, windows, debugging, sdk, libraries

I just have installed Windows SDK for php-debugging. But now I'm confused a little about which libraries to set for it. I went to https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/libs but there are lots of them and this questions is not clear for me... What I want just to make an ordinary debugging like to watch which methods are calling while script execution etc. Can anybody give me an advise?

Answer (score 1):

The page you linked discusses the libraries needed to *compile PHP from scratch*.  It does not discuss the thing you are interested in, which is:

> What I want just to make an ordinary debugging like to watch which methods are calling while script execution etc

For that, you just need [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/download.php), which even supplies precompiled binaries for you.  You will also need an IDE that speaks [DBGp](http://xdebug.org/docs-dbgp.php), a debugging protocol used by a number of debugging packages and IDEs.

Comment: That is both Eclipse with PDT or Netbeans, as IDEs. You can use also Zend debugger but with Eclipse only. I usually use WAMPServer with added xdebug and a browser plugin for enabling/disabling the debug.

Comment: Thanx, but one question more about xDebug. 
I have missed a point when it started working, probably it had happened after apache had rebooted. So it works now but I still can't see any information about called scripts. It shows me errors but I don't understand how to force it do other things. :(

Answer (score 0):

I found xDebug being best for me. It helps to trace your code and many more. I am using [PhpStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) as my IDE. Just [configure](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/configuring-xdebug.html) xDebug in your PhpStorm.